# socket.io rooms difference between to and in

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, chatroom

I'm trying to get myself acquainted with socket.io and node. https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

This is my reference.

```
var socketIO = require('socket.io')(http);
 socketIO.on('connection', function(socket) { 
 socket.join(data.room);})
 socketIO.in(users[key].room).emit('newmsg', data); 
        socketIO.to(users[key].room).emit('newmsg', data);
```

Here the code with socketIO.in gives output whereas socketIO.to doesn't
But as per their documentation in and to should return the same o/p.
Someone please explain to me the critical difference b/w them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right in the [socket.io doc](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/docs/API.md#namespaceinroom):

```
namespace.in(room)

Synonym of namespace.to(room).
```

So, `.to()` and `.in()` are the same.

---

And, if you look in [the code](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/db831a3de4528a2017dad5e9b419333d4d929bd3/lib/namespace.js#L147), you see this:

```
Namespace.prototype.to =
Namespace.prototype.in = function(name){
  if (!~this.rooms.indexOf(name)) this.rooms.push(name);
  return this;
};
```

So, both `.to()` and `.in()` run the exact same code so any difference you think you are seeing is not because of the difference between calling `.to()` or `.in()`.  It must be due to something else.  You'd have to show us a reproducible set of code that shows some difference for us to help you debug that.